# Convert text to binary and store in a single array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to convert the given text (not in file format) into binary values and store in a single array that is to be given as input to other function in Matlab .

Example:
Hi how are you ?

It is to be converted into binary and stored in an array.I have used dec2bin() function but i did not suceed in getting the output required.

Comment: It is part of my project where initially i have directly given an array with 0's and 1's as input but i was asked to embed text instead of binary digits i tried but could not get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like a trick question.  In MATLAB, a character array (string) is just a different representation of 16-bit unsigned character codes.

```
>> str = 'Hi, how are you?'
str =
Hi, how are you?
>> whos str
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  str       1x16               32  char
```

Note that the 16 characters occupy 32 bytes, or 2 bytes (16-bits) per character.  From the [documentation for `char`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html):

> Valid codes range from 0 to 65535, where codes 0 through 127 correspond to 7-bit ASCII characters. The characters that MATLAB® can process (other than 7-bit ASCII characters) depend upon your current locale setting. To convert characters into a numeric array,use the double function.

Now, you could use `double` as it recommends to get the character codes into `double` arrays, but a minimal representation would simply involve `uint16`:

```
int16bStr = uint16(str)
```

To split this into bytes, `typecast` into 8-bit integers:

```
typecast(int16bStr,'uint8')
```

which yields 32 `uint8` values (bytes), which are suitable for conversion to binary representation with [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html), if you want to see the binary (but these arrays are already binary data).

If you don't expect anything other than ASCII characters, just throw out the extra bits from the start:

```
>> int8bStr =
   72  105   44   32  104  111  119   32   97  114  101   32  121  111  117   63
>> binStr = reshape(dec2bin(binStr8b.'),1,[])
ans =
110011101110111001111111111111110000001001001011111011000000 <...snip...>
```